# How can I get the shortcuts of a given WPF command?

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

Given a WPF Button with a Command, how can I get the assigned shortcut (ex Copy -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can replace *ApplicationCommands.Copy* with the command you are looking for.

```
foreach (KeyBinding binding in InputBindings)
{
    if (binding.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(binding.Modifiers.ToString() + " + " + binding.Key.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I think this is the actual answer to your question:

```
Button b = new Button();

b.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy;

List<string> gestures = new List<string>();

if (b.Command is RoutedCommand)
{
    RoutedCommand command =  (b.Command as RoutedCommand);

    foreach (InputGesture gesture in command.InputGestures)
    {
        if (gesture is KeyGesture)
        gestures.Add((gesture as KeyGesture).DisplayString);
    }
}
```

If the reason you want to get is to display it in the button content, you can always do this:

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text}"></Button>
```

That will have the button say "New".

Answer (score -2):

Use KeyBinding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx

```
 <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C"
          Modifiers="Control" 
          Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
 </Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: No, he is asking how do you get the keyboard shortcut, not how to add the KeyBinding.